# how to 301 redrect from something like /index.php?sect=programs

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to 301 redirect `mydomainname.com/index.php?sect=programs` to `mydomainname.com`

I've tried this in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirects 301 /index.php?sect=programs http://mydomainname.com
```

but that doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: `Redirects` isn't an apache directive, but the query string doesn't belong in the `Redirect` directive anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your `mydomainname` site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?sect=programs\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomainname.com [L,R=301]
```